スプレッドシートでスクリプト実行時のアクセス権の承認ができない
「スプレッドシートでスクリプトを実行しようとするとアクセス権の承認を求められるが、承認のページが表示されない」
通常、「このアプリは Google で確認できません」と表示される場合は[詳細]から権限を確認できるようですが、
画面録画から確認したところ、アカウント管理の画面に移動してしまう。
アカウント管理画面より試し、
Check Sheet NotificationsとChromecastのアクセス権を一旦削除し、スクリプトを実行できるようになるか試したがそれでも変わらない。
